# "Passage linking that with this" vs "passage that links to this"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, comparative-constructions

From our comprehension exercise book:

> In the breeding season the water-spider picks out the house of a likely-looking female and builds himself a cottage next door, and then *presumably being of a romantic turn of mind, he builds a sort of secret passage linking his house with that of his lady-love.*

There's a question that asks to explain the italicised text:

> What does the writer mean by 'being of a romantic turn of mind'?

In my answer, I write:

> When the water-spider chooses a mate, he builds a **passage that links to** his lady’s house.

which is a shorter version of that. Note that it's not the complete answer, just the first sentence. I had to remove some words and ideas that aren't needed for the answer to make sense, for two reasons. One, the answer needs to be short and to-the-point. Two, it's important to reword the original text as much as possible—otherwise, it would just be copying directly from the passage.

But, I've some concerns about the phrase in bold:

> Does "***passage linking his house with that of his lady-love***" equate to "***a passage that links to his lady's house***"?

1. "*links X with Y*" vs. "*links to Y*"
2. "*his lady-love*" vs. "*his lady*"

Comment: Semantically they're equivalent.  A passage that links his house to his lady-love's house.  A passage linking their two houses. A passage linking his house to hers.

Comment: 1. They're obviously different since his cottage isn't mentioned in your sentence. 2. *Lady-love* is a lady who is loved by someone. The word *lady* doesn't bear these connotations by itself, but together with, for example, *his* it does. *Being of a romantic turn of mind* means he's romantically inclined.

Comment: @userr2684291 "Being of a romantic turn of mind means he's romantically inclined." I know. It's not a complete answer, as I said in my question.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine No, what I wrote is a complete answer. I see no reason to include what you wrote, however.

Comment: Perhaps you have not gotten an answer, but only comments, because the nature of your question is not very clear.   When you say **equates to** do you mean *in context* and allowing for reasonable inference, or are you asking the question as a nitpicking shady lawyer might? "Your honor, my client never said he would build the passage between the two houses, connecting them! The contract simply states that he would build a passage linking to his lady-love's house".